# exporting excel sheet from gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I'm exporting excel sheet from my gridview which i bind with dummy data. I'm using jquery mehod of exporting excel but its not working. i have the following function in jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function exportToExcel() 
    {
        var oExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        var oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add;
        var oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1);
        var detailsTable = document.getElementById('<%= gvSearchResult.ClientID %>');
        alert(detailsTable);
        for (var y=0;y<detailsTable.rows.length;y++) 
        // detailsTable is the table where the content to be exported is 
        { 
            for (var x=0;x<detailsTable.rows(y).cells.length;x++) 
            { 
                var cellData = detailsTable.rows(y).cells(x).innerText;
                var cellHTML = detailsTable.rows(y).cells(x).innerHTML;

                if (cellHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf("<table") == -1 && cellHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf("schedule") == -1) // check to omit page numbers
                {
                    oSheet.Cells(y+1,x+1) = cellData;
                }
            } 
        } 
        oExcel.Visible = true; 
        oExcel.UserControl = true; 
    }
```

i use the above function. i'm have a button on click i want to export the excel sheet. the button is as:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClickXport" Text="Xport2Xcel" OnClientClick="exportToExcel()" />
```

its not working. i test actually new ActiveXobject("Excel.Application"); in the start cause problem. what i need to do?

Comment: What does it mean **"I'm exporting excel sheet from my gridview"**? Are u trying to export gridview to excel or what?

Comment: Look at using OpenXML with [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

Comment: have you checked the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this jquery plugin to export an html table to csv:
https://code.google.com/p/jqtable2csv/

Example usage:

```
$("#my-table").table2csv({
    callback: function (csv, name) {
        jQuery.post(
            url, encodeURIComponent(csv),
             function (data) {
                 location.href = "/file?csv=" + csv + "&name=" + name;
             }
        );
});
```

That being said... if you are using ASP.Net you may want to handle this server side since there are some challenges with javascript initiating a download on older browsers.

Comment: He is using ASP.NET server control - GridView not jQUery plugin jqtable. But it's a good thing to know!

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code to export a `datagridview` to excel :

```
protected void ExportResultToExcel(string fileName)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        gvSearchResult.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: you can add it inside an `UpdatePanel`.